# discard count of \n in a string while using string.length in Javascript

Tags: javascript

"`HelloWorld`" consists of 10 characters

I have a string as

`var temp = "Hello\nWorld"`

When I use `temp.length` it returns 11 as it counts `\n` as a character. How do I only count characters?

Comment: Remove the `\n` characters first?

Comment: `\n` is counted as a character because it **is** a character.

Comment: `temp.replace(/\n/g, '').length`

Comment: `"Hello\nWorld".replace(/\n/g, '').length`

Comment: Do a count of `\n` and subtract from total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to firstly remove the \n:

```
temp.replace(/\n/g, '').length
```

String will still be:

```
temp = "Hello\nWorld"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `match()` to get count of line breaks and subtract from total length

```
var str = 'Hello\nWorld\n';
var breaks =str.match(/\n/g);
var count = str.length - (breaks ? breaks.length : 0);

alert(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
temp.match(/\w/g).length;
```

Comment: Will not match any special symbols if the string have any

Answer (score 0):

"Hello\nworld" returns 11 characters because \n also is a character.
so if you want to count how much characters in string, you need to remove any \n or \s firstly in .length